# Missing Details when Unable to resolve service when using NLOG

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog, asp.net-core-3.1

I just finished struggling with a generic error in AspNetCore3.1.  The error simply reads this:

> 2019-12-11 21:52:46.6862 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
>   Connection id "0HLRUMQV9RNJI", Request id "0HLRUMQV9RNJI:00000001": An
>   unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

After much pain, I found that it was because I missing a registration of a service:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // This service was missing
        services.AddTransient<IThingService, ThingService>();
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

So, now, I'm on a quest to find out why I didn't get any details on what the problem was.  I created a new Core 3.1 app from the Visual Studio templates.  I installed NLog.Web.AspNetCore and added an nlog.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\logs\nlog-internal.log">

    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    </extensions>

    <targets async="true">


        <target xsi:type="ColoredConsole" name="c" layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}" />


    </targets>

    <rules>

        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="c" />


    </rules>
</nlog>
```

AppSettings:

```
{
// I removed the logging section completely so that NLOG can control log levels
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I also added the following code to program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseIISIntegration()
                    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, loggingBuilder) =>
                    {
                        loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
                        loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                    })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseNLog();
            });
}
```

So then, I removed the registration of IThingService, and I started getting the same generic, useless error:

> "2019-12-11 21:52:46.6862 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
>   Connection id "0HLRUMQV9RNJI", Request id "0HLRUMQV9RNJI:00000001": An
>   unhandled exception was thrown by the application."

After some tinkering, I found that I commented out the line in program.cs, "loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();"  I started getting actual useful error messages:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'WebApplication3.Controllers.IThingService' while attempting to
>   activate 'WebApplication3.Controllers.WeatherForecastController'.

But, it's not NLog doing the logging, it's the default Core 3 logging.

Setup instructions for NLog can be found here:  https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3

So, now for the question, why does ClearProviders() make nlog work, but lose the details in my error messages?  It seems to only be logs that would take place down in the pipeline, not at the controller/domain level.

Comment: What happens if you remove `UseNLog()` and add `loggingBuilder.AddNLog()` inside `ConfigureLogging` at the bottom ?

Comment: That results in the useless variety of messages, "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel Connection id "0HLRUMQV9RNJI", Request id "0HLRUMQV9RNJI:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application."  It does come from NLog though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the special detail you are looking for is `${exception:format=tostring}`. Your current layout is this:

```
<target xsi:type="ColoredConsole" name="c" layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}" />
```

Try changing into this:

```
<target xsi:type="ColoredConsole" name="c" layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}${exception:format=tostring}" />
```

You might also consider including `${level}` in Layout (Unless coloring is enough).

Comment: Hahaha, that's perfect.  Sometimes the simplest answer is the right one.  It never dawned on me to check the layout.  A tip of the hat to you sir.